# Angular.js $http cors

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cors, angular-http

I am experiencing an issue with the $http service.

I have an php-server on an other localhost ip-address which serves as REST-API.
I tried this connection with some  `$http.get()` requests and everything worked fine, but it seems like something is blocking my `delete` or `put` requests. I tried to configure my http-requests with the `$httpProvider`

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

But this didn't worked either. 
I read that this is in most cases a server-issue but I had no problems to connect to the server using postman.

The Warning I get in the firefox-console is:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/testUrl (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).

I didn't found any similar issues through google for the newest version of angular. It might be possible that the usage of `$httpProvider` is deprecated since 1.2.

Kind regards,

Deleadon

Comment: Have you seen this website? It might have the answer you're looking for: http://enable-cors.org/index.html

Comment: So you haven't turned on CORS then?

Comment: postman is not subject to CORS. You need to implement CORS on rest server side. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/1175966

Answer (score 0):

I personally use this in Chrome to turn CORS on and off:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Simple UI - when it's green you know that CORS is on, when red you know that it's off.